# Integrating a Taylor series term-by-term

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, power-series

Why is  $$\int_{0}^{z} \frac{\sin x}{x} \ dx =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n+1)!} \int_{0}^{z} x^{2n} \ dx$$

not valid for $z= \infty$?

Well, at least I'm assuming it's not valid since otherwise it would appear to say that the the integral $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x}{x} \ dx$$ doesn't converge.

Comment: There's nothing I see about the series which suggests the integral won't converge. Think about the taylor series for $\exp(-x)$. As $x\rightarrow \infty$ the series approaches zero even though $x$ is infinite. So your series may still converge.

Comment: What are the first few terms of the series?

Comment: When converting from the left hand side to the right hand side, you are swapping limits. I am not sure if that is exactly the problem here, but you certainly have to be careful with it. For example, $$\lim_{m\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{m + n} = \lim_{m \to \infty} 1 = 1,$$ but $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{n}{m + n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0.$$

Comment: On any interval $[0,z]$ where $z$ is finite I think we can justify switching the order of integration and summation by the fact that the Taylor series converges uniformly.   But I'm not exactly sure what's going on at $\infty$.

Comment: Well you actually have 3 limits going on, so maybe its the limit of $z \to \infty$ that is resisting the swap.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \lim_{z\to\infty}\int_{1/z}^z \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \lim_{z \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^n\frac{\sin x_k^*}{x_k^*} \Delta x_k^*.$$

Now using the Taylor series, we have,
$$\lim_{z \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{k = 0}^n 
 \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{(-1)^j}{(2j + 1)!} (x_k^*)^{2j}
\Delta x_k^*.$$
Note: $x_k^*$ depends on $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have,

$$ \int_0^z \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int^z_0x^{2n}dx $$

I am going to go ahead and write $\int_0^z x^{2n} dx = z^{2n+1}/(2n+1)$ since the two are identical.

$$ \Rightarrow \int_0^z \frac{\sin(x)}{x} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)(2n+1)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nz^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)^2(2n)!} = Si(z) $$

Now you want to evaluate this for $z=\infty$. By definition the improper integral is,

$$\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^z f(x)dx$$

Therefore the answer you desire is,

$$ \lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^z \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} Si(z) = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

You can look up the properties of the $Si$ function [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html).

If I understand the issue correctly you were concerned that $\int_0^\infty x^2n dx=\infty$. That is never an issue here because that integral is never calculated. Instead we take the limit as $z\rightarrow \infty$ of the function defined by the resultant power series.